# How can I set and retain attributes on characters in a Python 2 string?

Tags: python, string

I would like to be able to add attributes to characters within a `str` or `unicode` string, chop the string and move pieces around, and have the attributes still be present at the end.

Would this be possible (and best) with a subclass of `str`, `unicode` or possibly `basestring`?

Example:

```
s = u"hello world"
s[6].foo = u'bar'
s2 = s.split(' ')
assert(s2 == u'world')
assert(s2[0].foo == u'bar')
```

Thanks for thoughts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using that as a starter:

```
class Mine(unicode):
    #
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Mine, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    #
    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        try:
            super(Mine, self).__setattr__(attr, value)
        except AttributeError:
            self.__dict__[attr] = value
    #
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        try:
            super(Mine, self).__getattr__(attr)
        except AttributeError:
            try:
                return self.__dict__[attr]
            except KeyError:
                raise AttributeError

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        obj = Mine(super(Mine, self).__getitem__(item))
        obj.__dict__ = self.__dict__
        return obj
```

Of course, you'll have to create a specific `split` method, where each item of the output list will be a `Mine` object:

```
def split(self, arg=' '):
    result = []
    for item in super(Mine, self).split(arg):
        i = Mine(item)
        i.__dict__ = self.__dict__
        result.append(i)
    return result
```

The generic idea is to overload **every** single method of the parent class (at least, the ones you're really interested in) so that it returns an instance of your class and inherits the `__dict__` of the caller... That can be a lot of work.

Comment: You'll have to overload any method - Mine('a') + 'a' will give you 'aa' and not Mine('aa') otherwise, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! It's not an easy one.

Answer (score 2):

`str` or `unicode` are built-in types, so you cannot set on them attributes without subclassing them anyway.

```
class CustomString(str): pass

obj = CustomString('a')
obj.attr = 1 #works
''.attr = 1 #AttributeError
```

That is for custom attributes on `str`.

However, this still doesn't help, because you still cannot change the string, as `str` and `unicode` are immutable.

The only option you get is to use `bytearray`s, which are mutable byte arrays. You'll have to encode unicode manually, though. (and you still have to subclass it to assign attributes!)